# jquery error: val() is not a function

Tags: jquery

Why I'm getting this error? `val is not a function` when I validate the number.

```
$(this).find('#register-validation .next').click(function() {
     var _parent = $(this).parents('#register-validation');
     $('.loading-big').html(loadMsg).fadeIn(300);
     _parent.find('input.required').each(function(index) {
         if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == errReq) { // here is fine
             $(this).val(errReq);
             $(this).addClass("error");
         }
         else if(isNaN($(this).hasClass('number').val())) { // but when validation goes here, I got this error.
             $(this).val(errNum);
             $(this).addClass("error");
         }
         else {
             $(this).removeClass("error");
         }
     });
});
```

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @corroded i guess `($(this).val() == "" ||`

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).hasClass('number').val()
```

That line is causing your problem. You are calling .val() on the boolean returned by hasClass(). You have to be a bit careful when chaining methods as although most will return the jquery object some return different values and therefore can't be chained.

Try this instead:

```
$('.number', this).val()
```

This will select all elements with the class of number in the context of this. It's the same as doing `$(this).find('.number').val()`

Answer (score 2):

```
 else if(isNaN($(this).hasClass('number').val())) {
```

should be

```
 else if($(this).hasClass('number') && isNaN($(this).val())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).hasClass('number')` returns a boolean as far as I know, so you can't chain it.

Also you might want consider caching the jquery object so that it doesn't have to create the object over and over again.

Simply putting `$this = $(this)` inside your method and referring to `$this` will improve your performance a wee bit.